# Mixins scss doesn't work

Tags: css, svg, png, sass, mixins

I'm trying to create a mixin in scss that will help me to handle svg as background with a fallback to png for old browser.

The problem is that it doesn't work.
I have only one css file like this

```
@mixin background-svg-support($png, $svg) {
  background: transparent url($png) center center no-repeat;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url($svg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url($svg);
}
.bg {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  @inlude background-svg-support('http://bit.ly/14U3Qui', 'http://bit.ly/99Xewi');
}
```

but no matter how, I can't get to have the backgrounds properties in my `.bg`class.
What's wrong here ? [Here is the codepen link](http://codepen.io/Micka33/pen/jLJhd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nevermind, I had written`@inlude` instead of `@include`. It works now as intended.

I have corrected the codepen as well to make it work.